# UITableViewController is blank after receiving a memory warning

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I'm drawing a table view in MonoTouch by subclassing `UITableViewController` and `UITableViewSource` (not `UITableViewDataSource`!!!). In the constructor of my view controller, I set the table view source like that:

```
TableView.Source = new CustomTableViewSource();
```

And in my `CustomTableViewSource`, I'm constructing the cell of the table view. It's work great except when I am simulating a memory warning in the iPhone simulator. If the view is hidden (e.g. an other view controller in the tab bar is selected), when I come back, the table view is just blank (white background, no table view anymore).

However, I'm doing nothing in the `DidReceiveMemoryWarning` callback. I also tried to set again the `TableViewSource` in the `viewWillAppear` (if received a memory warning) but no no more success...

Is it a garbage collector issue? I know that `GC.Collect` is called when receiving memory warning. Maybe the Garbage collector is just throwing away my view and I need to display it entirely again?

Comment: Post your `ViewDidLoad` and `ViewDidUnload` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be initializing the table source in the ViewDidLoad method and not in the constructor. That method is called when a view controller is loaded and then every time the controller's view needs to be re-created after a memory warning.

I've done some tests and I get similar results after a memory warning. However, I only get an empty table view. When I set the table source in the ViewWillAppear again, the table is populated with data normally.

The fact that your implementation in the ViewWillAppear does not work, makes me think that the method does not even get called. If that is the case, I am guessing that your table view is not being re-created when it needs to.

This can happen under certain circumstances when you are using controllers whose views are not created from a XIB file. In this case, you should create the view in the LoadView method (without calling base.LoadView()):

```
public override void LoadView()
{
    this.View = new UITableView(UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame); //or something similar
}
```

I had similar problems (table views where not re-created) with a complex hierarchy of tab controllers that contained navigation controllers, that contained view controllers etc. The problems were solved when I provided the LoadView method.

I'm out of guesses ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's fixed my issue! Sorry, I should have provided more information. As you guessed, I'm not using a XIB file but creating my table view with code. `LoadView()` was not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that `GC.Collect()` will be called when a memory warning is received. This is a serious warning from the operating system and MonoTouch will try to release it's own memory (if possible). You can extend this, by overriding `DidReceiveMemoryWarning`, so your application can also release any memory that it does not absolutely requires.

This call to the GC (like any other) means that every object that is not referenced can be collected and freed. Now your `CustomTableViewSource` instance should not be collected (unless your `TableView` is). In doubt you can check this by adding a finalizer for the type, E.g.

```
~CustomTableViewSource ()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("~CustomTableViewSource");
}
```

However the objects that are part of your `CustomTableViewSource` *could* be collected (if not referenced) as other parts (UI) of your table could be. That's impossible to tell without seeing the source code.

I suggest you to try to find out what's being freed and from there you should see what's needed to either keep a reference (to avoid them being collected) or what needs to be recreated (if some instances were freed on purpose).

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, my solution that is working is:

```
public class LoginViewController : UITableViewController
{
  LoginDataSource m_loginDataSource;

  public LoginViewController(UITableViewStyle withStyle) : base(withStyle)
  {
   m_loginDataSource = new LoginDataSource(this);
  }

  public override void LoadView()
  {
    this.View = new UITableView(UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame,  UITableViewStyle.Grouped);
  }

  public override void ViewDidLoad ()
  {
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    TableView.Source = m_loginDataSource;
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to get it that complex. Just do TableView.Source=new LoginDataSource(this) inside the ViewDidLoad method.